# Powershell - Calling Property Inside Expression

Tags: powershell, expression

Could you please advise, why does this work:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {DisplayName -like "*Name*"} |
  fl Displayname, PrimarySMTPAddress, @{Label = "Members"; expression = {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Identity |
      select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress
  }}
```

And that does not:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {DisplayName -like "*Name*"} |
  fl Displayname, PrimarySMTPAddress, @{Label = "Members"; expression = {
    (Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Identity).PrimarySmtpAddress
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many members you get back (the second command would work if the result is one object long).

The first command pipes the result to select-object which expands all group members (the members collection is unrolled and each member is piped to select-object, one at a time).

The second command gets the collection of members and is asked to display the primary address of the **collection itself**, not each member's address, which results in nothing cause the collection doesn't have a PrimarySmtpAddress property.

to make the second command work you'd need to pipe to Foreach-Object first:

```
... @{Label = "Members"; expression = {(Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Identity | Foreach-Object {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider marking it as the answer in case it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you describe the problem in more detail than "does not work" - if there's an error message, give that. If you get unexpected results, describe what you expected and what you got instead.

`Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Identity | select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress` returns a string.

`(Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Identity).PrimarySmtpAddress` returns an object.

Comment: Idea is to get this command return some Distribution Group properties and members of Distribution Group without additional pipe lining
First command returns all members of the Distribution Group